# how to redirect in jquery fancybox pop up to next page...in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

I m using jquery fancy box popup window....for pop up....
But when i submit ...my form that redirect in same window.....in popup..
I want  to redirect  my page to another open window....not in same popup...

I used target blank ..but it work every..time on click...i need to redirect when i got my login is done....
I m creating my project in codeigniter.....

my controller....

```
public function login()
    { 
        if ( $this->input->post('action') )
        {       
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'Username','required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|');


            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
            {

                $username  =  $this->input->post('user_name');
                $password  =  $this->input->post('password');               
                $rember    =  ($this->input->post('remember')!="") ? TRUE : FALSE;

                 if( $this->input->post('remember')=="Y" )
                 {
                        set_cookie('userName',$this->input->post('user_name'), time()+60*60*24*30 );
                        set_cookie('pwd',$this->input->post('password'), time()+60*60*24*30 );
                  }
                  else
                  {                      
                        delete_cookie('userName');
                        delete_cookie('pwd');
                  }     

                $this->auth->verify_user($username,$password);  

                if( $this->auth->is_user_logged_in() )
                {
                      if( $this->session->userdata('ref')!=""  )
                      { 

                        redirect($this->session->userdata('ref'),'');   

                      }
                      else
                      {

                         redirect('members/myaccount','refresh'); 

                      }


                }
                else
                {

                    $this->session->unset_userdata(array("ref"=>'0'));
                    $this->session->set_userdata(array('msg_type'=>'error'));
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$this->config->item('login_invalid'));        
                    redirect('users/login', '');
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $data['heading_title'] = "Login";           
                $this->load->view('users_login',$data); 
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            $data['heading_title'] = "Login";           
            $this->load->view('users_login',$data);     
        }
    }
```

```js
$(window).load(function (e) {
    $("#back-top").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        })
    });

    $(".login").fancybox({
        'width': 367,
        'height': 600,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });

    $(".fotget").fancybox({
        'width': 425,
        'height': 286,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });

    $(".profile").fancybox({
        'width': 700,
        'height': 505,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });

    $(".details").fancybox({
        'width': 400,
        'height': 200,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });

    $(".enquiry").fancybox({
        'width': 359,
        'height': 450,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });

    $(".contact").fancybox({
        'width': 317,
        'height': 353,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });

    $(".map").fancybox({
        'width': 425,
        'height': 355,
        'autoScale': false,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason this is happening is because your popup content is iframed... you could send a message back to the parent window to do the redirect in the main browser window, a google on iframe communication to it's parent window should get you the info you need to do this, however this all hinges on you having control of the page being iframed!

EXAMPLE:...where ever your redirects are...replace with...

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.top.postMessage('logged_in', '*');</script>";
exit; //make sure this is here, to stop php execution!!
```

Then in your parent window (the one intitializing the fancyboxes...)

```
window.onmesage = function(e){ 
  if(e.data == 'logged_in'){ 
    window.location.href = 'http://pathtopage';
  }
}
```

NOTE: 'logged_in' could also be json string

```
'{ "action":"something","redirect":"http://url" }'
```

just use

```
JSON.parse(e.data);
```

in the listener to extract the json object

EDIT: well crap... I misunderstood your question... I don't see the element you are using to submit the form... but generally you would do e.preventDefault(); on that element before letting it redirect anywhere....so for example you are using an anchor tag...

```
$('a.form-submit').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var redir = $(this).attr('href');
  var formData = $('#theform').serialize();
  $.post('http://formhandler/route',formdata,function(){
    //open a new window...
    window.open(redir);
    //or send data back to parent window...
    window.top.postMessage(redir,'*');
  });
});
```